# karma-webpack could not find module 'react'

Tags: reactjs, webpack, karma-runner, commonjs

I've been trying to get put together very simple demonstration of using karma and react, and eventually writing tests for React, but I've been stuck for the last 10 hours and I'm hoping someone has encountered this before and can tell me what silly little thing I'm missing or not understanding.

Here's my karma.conf.js:

```
// Karma configuration
// Generated on Sun Apr 10 2016 10:10:34 GMT-0700 (PDT)

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',

    resolve: {
      extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx','.ts']
    },
    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['commonjs','jasmine'],


    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
      // only specify one entry point
      // and require all tests in there
      //'node_modules/babel-polyfill/browser.js',
      //'node_modules/react/react.js',
      'test_index.js'
    ],

    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [
    ],

    preprocessors: {
      'node_modules/react/react.js':['babel','commonjs'],
      'src/**/*.js':['babel','commonjs'],
      'spec/**/*.js':['babel','commonjs'],
      'test_index.js': ['babel','commonjs','webpack']
    },

    babelPreprocessor: {
      options: {
        presets: ['es2015','react']
      }
    },




    webpack: {
      module : {
        loaders: [ {
          loader : 'babel-loader',
          query: {
            presets: ['es2015','react']
          }
        }
        ]
      }
    },

    webpackMiddleware: {
      // webpack-dev-middleware configuration
      // i. e.
      noInfo: true
    },

    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['progress'],


    // web server port
    port: 9876,


    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,


    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: false,


    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: [],


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: false,

    // Concurrency level
    // how many browser should be started simultaneous
    concurrency: Infinity
  })
}
```

When I do karma run I get the following error:

```
Chrome 49.0.2623 (Mac OS X 10.10.5) ERROR
  Uncaught Error: Could not find module 'react' from '/Users/chris/web-projects/project-template/src/scripts/app.js'
  at /Users/chris/web-projects/project-template/node_modules/karma-commonjs/client/commonjs_bridge.js:85
```

If you want to take a look at any of my other files, you can access the current branch of the repo here:

https://github.com/watzthisco/tdd-react-es6/tree/lab18

Thank you for any help you can provide!
-Chris

Answer (score 0):

Change your `resolve` from

```
resolve: {
  extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx','.ts']
},
```

to

```
resolve: {
  modulesDirectories: [
    'node_modules'
  ],
  extensions: ['', '.json', '.js']
},
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I got this working. I *think* my problem was too many preprocessors, but I'm actually not really sure. Here's my karma.conf.js now:

```
// Karma configuration
// Generated on Sun Apr 10 2016 10:10:34 GMT-0700 (PDT)

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',

    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],


    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
      // only specify one entry point
      // and require all tests in there
      //'node_modules/babel-polyfill/browser.js',
      //'node_modules/react/react.js',
      'test_index.js'
    ],

    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [
    ],

    preprocessors: {
      'src/**/*.js':['babel','webpack'],
      'spec/**/*.js':['babel','webpack'],
      'test_index.js': ['babel','webpack']
    },

    babelPreprocessor: {
      options: {
        presets: ['es2015','react']
      }
    },

    webpack: {
      module : {
        loaders: [ {
          loader : 'babel-loader',
          query: {
            presets: ['es2015','react']
          }
        }
        ]
      }

    },

    webpackMiddleware: {
      // webpack-dev-middleware configuration
      // i. e.
      noInfo: true
    },

    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['progress'],


    // web server port
    port: 9876,


    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,


    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: false,


    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: [],


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: false,

    // Concurrency level
    // how many browser should be started simultaneous
    concurrency: Infinity
  })
}
```

It's loading modules fine now, but now it's telling me:

Uncaught Invariant Violation: _registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM element.

I don't get this when I do a normal build with webpack, just through karma.